How to Prevent LiDAR Localization Loss During High-Velocity Rotation
I am working with a mobile robot equipped with a LiDAR sensor, and I've encountered an issue where the LiDAR seems to shift or misalign with the robot's frame during rotations at higher velocities and looses localization. Specifically, the issue occurs when the robot's max_vel_x and max_vel_theta are set above 0.6, and it happens shortly after the robot starts rotating. The LiDAR alignment to the map seems to stabilize after a few seconds, but the temporary misalignment is causing some issues with localization and mapping.
Here are some details about my setup:
LiDAR model: SLAMTEC RPLiDAR S2E - 2nos
System environment: ros2 Humble
param.yaml:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 2.0
    alpha2: 1.0
    alpha3: 1.0
    alpha4: 2.0
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: -1.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    initial_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    set_initial_pose: True
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    update_min_a: 0.01
    update_min_d: 0.01
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan    
amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False    
amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False    
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node    
bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False    
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 10.0
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]    
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0    
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17    
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: -0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.6  
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.6
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.62
      min_speed_theta: 0.05
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 4.0
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.8 
      vx_samples: 200
      vy_samples: 0 
      vtheta_samples: 40
      sim_time: 1.5
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.3
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.325
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.325
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 20.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0          
controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False    
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 10.0
      publish_frequency: 5.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_footprint
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 5
      height: 5
      resolution: 0.1
      robot_radius: 0.42
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 15.0
        inflation_radius: 0.2
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        inflation_radius: 0.1     
        observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
        lidar_front_right/scan:
          topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
        lidar_rear_left/scan:
          topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
        lidar_front_right/scan:
          topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        lidar_rear_left/scan:
          topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 6.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True    
global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 10.0
      publish_frequency: 5.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_footprint
      use_sim_time: false
      robot_radius: 0.42
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        inflation_radius: 0.6
        observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
        lidar_front_right/scan:
          topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 6.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        lidar_rear_left/scan:
          topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 6.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      voxel_layer:  
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
        lidar_front_right/scan:
          topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        lidar_rear_left/scan:
          topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 25.0
        inflation_radius: 0.6
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False    
map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "em3.yaml"    
map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5000  
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True    
planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 1.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 1.0  #foxy 1.0
      use_astar: true  #foxy true
      allow_unknown: true    
planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False    
recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 1.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: false
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 0.3 
    min_rotational_vel: 0.05
    rotational_acc_lim: 1.2   
robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False    
waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 2000  ####20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    # General parameters
    update_rate: 20.0    
    smoother_type: "velocity_smoother"
    velocity_smoother:
      type: "nav2_smoother::VelocitySmoother"
      lookahead_time: 0.5
      samples: 10
      min_samples: 5
      max_samples: 20
      alpha: 0.8
      beta: 0.2
      max_velocity_xy: 0.5
      max_velocity_theta: 0.5
      smoothing_frequency: 80.0
    motion_model_for_search: "DifferentialDrive"
    pose_distance: 0.25
    publish_predicted_path: false
    publish_filtered_path: false    
realsense_node:
  ros__parameters:
    topics:
      color:
        image: "/camera/color/image_raw"
        camera_info: "/camera/color/camera_info"
      depth:
        image: "/camera/depth/image_rect_raw"
      infra1:
        image: "/camera/infra1/image_rect_raw"
      infra2:
        image: "/camera/infra2/image_rect_raw"
    depth_scale_meters: 0.001
behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
    backup.plugin: nav2_behaviors/BackUp
    behavior_plugins:
      - spin
      - backup
      - drive_on_heading
      - wait
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    cycle_frequency: 20.0
    drive_on_heading.plugin: nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_frame: odom
    max_rotational_vel: 0.1
    min_rotational_vel: 0.05
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    rotational_acc_lim: 2.0
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    spin.plugin: nav2_behaviors/Spin
    transform_tolerance: 0.5
    use_sim_time: false
    wait.plugin: nav2_behaviors/Wait        
velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
    feedback: OPEN_LOOP
    odom_duration: 0.1
    odom_topic: /odom
    scale_velocities: true
    smoothing_frequency: 150.0
    use_sim_time: False
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

ekf config file
ekf_filter_node: ros__parameters:

use_sim_time: false
frequency: 30.0

sensor_timeout: 0.1

two_d_mode: true

transform_time_offset: 0.0

transform_timeout: 0.0

print_diagnostics: true

debug: false

debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt

publish_tf: false

publish_acceleration: false

map_frame: map                 
odom_frame: /odom                
base_link_frame: /base_footprint 
world_frame: /odom                

odom0: /odom

odom0_config: [true, true, true,
               false, false, true,
               true,  true,  true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]

odom0_queue_size: 2

odom0_nodelay: false

odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: true

odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

imu0: /imu_data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  false,
              true, true, true,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]

imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 7
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  

imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

use_control: false

stamped_control: false

control_timeout: 0.2

control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]

acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]

deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]

acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]

deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

process_noise_covariance: [0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025,   0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]

initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]

There are a couple of tests i have completed for testing to see how good the odometry of a robot is:

Test 1: Open up rviz and make sure that you're subscribed to the laser scan topic for your robot. Next, set the decay time to something like 30 seconds. Also set the fixed frame to the odom frame. Perform an in-place rotation with the robot and look at the laser scans. If odometry is fairly accurate, you should see scans from the previous rotation overlap with those generated on the current rotation. You'll want to do this in an area where you have distinctive features in your laser scan.

Test 2: Set up rviz the same way as the previous test. Point the robot at a wall and drive it towards it. With good odometry, the wall should stay in about the same place as the robot moves towards it. If you see a lot of movement in the positions of the scans relative to the wall that means odometry is poor.

Test 3: Drive the robot straight down a hallway. The laser scans of the hallway should stay straight. If you see them move a lot, it means your odometry is poor.


I have checked tread size its all perfect.
here i added the param and ekf.yaml files and rviz running video:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1415Q_JOubg6PHrCnw_o0JKxXoDoCEx71?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O4nIPJ7vTGfFQLzspBhovk03xjkOyLa2

Could this behavior be caused by motion distortion, sensor fusion issues, or something else related to velocity and sensor calibration? How can I prevent the LiDAR shift from happening during rotations at higher velocities?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Given your EKF subscribes to Odometry and IMU messages in the following manner:
#  [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
#   roll    , pitch    , yaw,
#   x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
#   roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
#   x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]

and therefore with odom0 regarding your orientation to odom0:yaw:
odom0_config: [true, true, true,
               false, false, true,
               true,  true,  true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false] 

and regarding your imu0 to imu0:yaw_vel:
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  false,
              true, true, true,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]

This means the EKF will have to estimate the robot's heading yaw and heading velocity yaw_vel according to the built-in kinematics (process) and your sensor input odom0:yaw and imu0:yaw_vel. wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Details, you will see that a Kalman filter does two steps: Predict and Update where the associated Covariance-Matrices are essentials "weights" on sensor input and process.

example: your variance on the process regarding yaw is HIGH and on the imu0:yaw_vel is LOW, the the kalman filter will converge towards the process yaw

example: your variance on the sensor imu0:yaw_vel is LOW and the variance on the odom0:yaw_vel is HIGH, the Kalman filter will "trust" the imu0 more than the odometry and converge towards the imu0:yaw_vel.


If you experience slow convergence, it means your process and sensor are contradicting (not the same value), e.g.:
a. example: process yaw says the yaw value is stationary at $0.5rad$ but imu0:yaw_vel reports a yaw_vel of $1rad/s$. Depending on the variances it will try and drift AWAY from stationary $0.5rad$ since the IMU says it's drifting, but STAY at stationary $0.5rad$ because the process says so.
the same will be true if you have two contradicting sensors. To get fast convergence in EKF, make sure to e.g.(!) have a HIGH process variance (aka do not trust your kinematic model of your robot) and LOW sensor variance (aka trust your sensor), and make sure you nothing contradicts.
As a start, use  plotjuggler to look at your data, and try and fuse as little data as possible, e.g.:
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false] 

imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false,  false,  false,
              false, false, true,
              false,  false,  false,
              false,  false,  false]

and keep adding new sensor data when you are sure the already added data makes sense. Please also make sure to use RVIZ to look into your EKF output odometry message to see if the robot actually moves the way you expect.

If you are relying on AMCL to fix your drift issues, the correction to the robot's pose often does not happen quickly.
With an accurate map and laser scan data, you could use a Localization Tracker to correct the drift. In theory a tracker is able to correct your robot's map pose with each LaserScan msg, but be aware that a tracker assumes the robot is already pretty accurately localized. A tracker is generally not a replacement for AMCL.
